# how to define any variable in <lable> tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i am trying to define variable in  tag but i am getting null as response.

```html
    <script>
            var check= "abc";
            document.getElementById('xyz').value = check
     </script>
        
     <td>
        <label for="xyz" style="padding-right:5px;">
        </label>
     </td>
```

i am getting "**Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property 'value' of null**".
no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You're missing an element with an ID of `xyz`. Plus the script wouldn't see it anyway being above the target HTML.

Comment: And the `<script>` should be after the `<label>` or the tag that contains the `id=` so it is run after it's displayed. (for safety)

Comment: Script tag below, make sure 'xyz' is an ID, and if you use jQuery you can just do... $("[for='xyz']").val(check); with regular JS you need to do some more lines of code to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML` to set a label.

```html
  
<td>
   <label id="xyz" style="padding-right:5px;">
   </label>
</td>
<script>
   var check= "abc";
   document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML= check
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the label add  id="xyz" and remove for="xyz".

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label id="xyz" style="padding-right:5px;">
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var check = "abc";       
    document.getElementById('xyz').innerText = check;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use innerText or innerHTML.